# Can T-SQL function return user-defined table type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, function, user-defined-functions

I have my own type:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE
(
    foo INT
)
```

and a function receiving it as a parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test
(
    @in MyType READONLY
)
RETURNS @return MyType
AS
...
```

can it return `MyType` or only `TABLE` repeating MyType's structure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test
(
    @in MyType READONLY
)
RETURNS @return TABLE (foo INT)
AS
...
```

?

Comment: @KM: Yes and got no success. So want to clarify

Comment: @GSerg: yeah, agreed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I understand Microsoft's [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), those user-defined table types are only available as *read-only parameters* to stored procedures or stored functions.

It doesn't mention anything that they could be used to be returned from a user-defined function, unfortunately - so I guess you're right - it's not possible (at least not now).