# How to make a function that take user defined table type as parameter and return same in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, user-defined-types

Actually I have created a User defined table type in sql server 2008. Structure is given below.

I am passing it as parameter in function and that function also return that type of table type. I am facing the problem, while I declare a variable of that type in function, inserting some data in it and return that parameter.

Table type structure is:

```
Create Type OfferWithSubscription  as  Table                                        
   (                                        
     OfferID int, 
     OfferUserID  int,                                    
     OfferImage  varchar(200),                          
     OfferExactPrice Decimal(18,2),                                
     OfferContent varchar(max),
     OfferTitle varchar(100),                                    
     StartDate datetime,                                    
     EndDate datetime,                                    
     StartTime datetime,                                    
     StopTime datetime,                            
     ShowToUser bit,    
     SubID  int,                    
     SubLevel varchar(100)
   )
```

And the function, what I am trying to create is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_ShowOffer
(   
    @Gold int,
    @Silver int,
    @Bronze int,
    @table dbo.OfferWithSubscription Readonly )
RETURNS dbo.OfferWithSubscription 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ReturnTable AS dbo.OfferWithSubscription;
Declare @Case as varchar(20)
         if(@Gold=0 and @Silver=1 and @Bronze=0 )
            begin
            set @Case='1S'
            end
           if(@Case='1S')
           Begin
                   insert into @ReturnTable                                    
                   select OfferID, OfferUserID, OfferImage, 
                     OfferExactPrice, OfferContent,
                     OfferTitle, StartDate, EndDate, 
                     StartTime, StopTime, ShowToUser,
                     SubID, SubLevel
                   from @table
                   where SubID=4 
           End

RETURN (

@ReturnTable
)
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just have to expand the type like below.
FYI - [Can T-SQL function return user-defined table type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501324/can-t-sql-function-return-user-defined-table-type)

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_ShowOffer
(   
    @Gold int,
    @Silver int,
    @Bronze int,
    @table dbo.OfferWithSubscription Readonly )
RETURNS @ReturnTable Table                                        
   (                                        
     OfferID int, 
     OfferUserID  int,                                    
     OfferImage  varchar(200),                          
     OfferExactPrice Decimal(18,2),                                
     OfferContent varchar(max),
     OfferTitle varchar(100),                                    
     StartDate datetime,                                    
     EndDate datetime,                                    
     StartTime datetime,                                    
     StopTime datetime,                            
     ShowToUser bit,    
     SubID  int,                    
     SubLevel varchar(100)
   )
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Case as varchar(20)
         if(@Gold=0 and @Silver=1 and @Bronze=0 )
            begin
            set @Case='1S'
            end
           if(@Case='1S')
           Begin
           insert into @ReturnTable                                    
             select OfferID,OfferUserID,OfferImage,OfferExactPrice,OfferContent,OfferTitle,
             StartDate,EndDate,StartTime,StopTime,ShowToUser,SubID,SubLevel from @table where SubID=4 
           End

RETURN
END
```

And to further clarify, that's fully compatible and assignable to a variable of that table type, e.g. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de117/2/0)

```
declare @t OfferWithSubscription
insert @t
select * from fn_showoffer(1,2,3,@t)
```

Comment: Mr. Mahmoud Gamal,it is showing the error that 
"Must declare the scalar variable "@ReturnTable"."

Comment: Did you miss the line `RETURNS @ReturnTable Table` in the function header?

Comment: Mr. Richard ,Can you tell me how to execute this function and test it?
I try it like it,
exec dbo.FN_ShowOffer(@G,@S,@B,@TestTable)

but it shows error.....

Comment: Click on the 2nd "SQL Fiddle" link in the answer... Run the left content in SSMS, then the right content in another window. You do not execute table functions, you `SELECT` from them.

Comment: I don't get it - you're defining @t as the image of calling fn_showoffer by providing @t? Is this a recursion?